# How should I include files with an app that a user can transfer onto their lap/desktop

Tags: iphone, ios, file, synchronization, transfer

I would like to include an mp3 with an iPhone application which a user can copy from the application to their desktop or laptop during sync. I'm unsure what to look at for achieving this. Can someone point me in the right direction or better still offer an outline of what this would involve?

Answer (score 1):

May be file sharing is what you are looking for.

See [File sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4094)

To enable file sharing for your application, do the following:

Add the UIFileSharingEnabled key to your application’s Info.plist file and set the value of the key to YES.

Put whatever files you want to share in your application’s Documents directory.

When the device is plugged into the user’s computer, iTunes 9.1 displays a File Sharing section in the Apps tab of the selected device.

The user can add files to this directory or move files to the desktop.